# Struggling to get if statement to work in Javascript with JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The aim of this code is to alter a piece of text on a page so that it is changed from the word reported to pending upon clicking a button. I want to write an if statement so that an error message will appear should the text already read pending.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  <?php echo "$(\"#ack".$i."\").click(function(){"; ?>
    <?php echo "if ($(\"#status".$i."\").val() == \"Pending\")"; ?>
      alert("boo"); 
    else 
      <?php echo  "$(\"#status".$i."\").text('Pending');"; ?>
  });
});
```

Currently the web app just ignores the if statement; the alert never appears when the button is clicked on an row which already has the status pending. Am I taking the right approach to this? What should I change in the if statement so that JS will check the value of status and open the alert if it contains the text "pending"?

Comment: Check the source of the page and add the actual html (without the PHP code)

Comment: Is this being created in a loop in php? Do you have `n` number of these code blocks in javascript? You could simplify this all by using classes instead of ids.

Comment: First, it'll be easier to work if you use output buffering like so:

    ob_start();
    ?>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){}); // and so on
    <?php
    echo ob_get_clean();

This will allow you to write plain JavaScript without escaping. Use <?php echo ''; ?> within the output buffer to access variables.

Comment: check if this `$("#status<?= $i?>").val()` return the correct value or even select your target element by alerting it `alert ($("#status<?= $i?>").val())`

Comment: The app just seems to be ignore the if statement altogether and executes everything above and below lines three and five. Is the code I've written for and if statement in JS correct?

Comment: he meant, you could print an `alert` just above the `if` to check why you're not meeting the condition (BTW, you could also use `console.log`)

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you are setting the `.text()` while checking on the `.val()`

most likely you would want to make them both the same

so, depending on what type of HTML element you have there in your `#statusX`, if it is a `<input>` or some form element, then change both to `.val()`, and vice-versa